# Pyautogui. How to make if the code does not find the image so that it does not click

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

When pyautogui doesn't find the image, it still clicks, how to avoid this?
Code:

```
while True:
     import pyautogui as a


     click = 'photoes/fish.png'
     samo = a.locateOnScreen(click)

     a.click(samo)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui as pag
click = 'photos/fish.png'
try:
    samo = pag.locateOnScreen(click)
    pag.click(samo)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File Not Found.")
```

I'm not sure that I fully understand what you are trying to accomplish, but locateOnScreen(click) returns a FileNotFoundError exception if it cannot find the file on the screen. The above code uses a try block to isolate that exception. If the file is found, it will perform the click operation. On my machine, since the file is not found it simply prints "File Not Found."